# Add mod_mysql, mod_xml and mod_zlib to apache

Tags: mysql, xml, apache, module, zlib

I was in the process of Anahita installation - a platform for social networking. In its requirements there is a line which says:

> Apache 2.0+ (with mod_mysql, mod_xml, mod_zlib) or Nginx

You can find its main website [here](https://www.getanahita.com) and its installation guide [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-apache-web-server-on-an-ubuntu-or-debian-vps)
I installed apache2 (ubuntu 14.04) but when I go to /etc/apache2/mods-available there are no mod_mysql, mod_xml or mod_zlib. 

how should I add these modules to apache? 
I couldn't find them in modules.apache.org

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When they talk about "`mod_mysql`, `mod_xml`, `mod_zlib`" they are not talking about Apache modules but rather about php extensions also sometimes called modules. Go to `php.ini` and enable `mysql`, `xml-rpc` and `zlib`. Depending on your platform and php distribution you may need to download correct libraries and configure the PATH to your php and mysql.

Comment: Note: before people panic `php_zlib` is now part of the PHP core so an extension is no longer present and you dont need to panic if you cannot find it.