# Joomla upgrade requirements

Tags: php, joomla

I need to upgrade Joomla from 2.5.28 to 3.5.1. However, when I attempt the upgrade, I get an error which states 
"We can't install the update to 3.5.1 as your host doesn't support the minimum requirements for Joomla 3.5.1 and there is no alternative available."

I've checked all of the requirements listed here but the error message doesn't tell me which ones haven't been met: [Link](https://downloads.joomla.org/technical-requirements)

I am 100% certain that the core versions of PHP, MySQL, and Apache all meet or exceed the minimum requirements, however, I'm not sure about the notes for PHP and Apache, specifically this:
Magic Quotes GPC, MB String Overload = off
Zlib Compression Support, XML Support, INI Parser Support, JSON Support, Mcrypt Support, MB Language = Default
and this:
with mod_mysql, mod_xml, and mod_zlib

I don't have a lot of experience with PHP. how do I check for all of the above PHP configs/modules? It seems that PHP -m is not enough.

Regarding Apache, I found another post which claims that the Apache modules are NOT actual Apache modules but PHP modules [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33386901/add-mod-mysql-mod-xml-and-mod-zlib-to-apache)

Is that correct? Why would the Joomla doc list those dependencies as Apache modules? Also, if that's correct, does "mod_xml" really map to the XML-RPC module?

Comment: If you sure the php and mysql version are right you can try update your site in local macchine (xampp) and upload all online later.

Answer (score 2):

One non-technical solution would be to create a temporary blank database and begin the installation of a fresh version of Joomla 3.5.1 in a temporary directory of your web space. Then check what happens at step 3 of the installation process where there's a pre-installation check.

You can [download Joomla 3.5.1 here](https://downloads.joomla.org/cms/joomla3/3-5-1)

Attached is an example of the pre-installation check list results for 3.7

Good luck!

[image]

Comment: Following up. . . that worked perfectly.  Thanks @david-taiaroa